# What do the -0 and -1 scores in the FIDE Grand Swiss mean?

Tags: tournament, scoring

[Link to results](https://chess-results.com/tnr793016.aspx?lan=1&art=4&flag=30)

The last two rounds saw three players score "-0" (GM Kollars Dmitrij and IM Amar Elham), and one person score "-1" (GM Fier Alexandr). They don't look like standard scores (0, 1/2, 1). What do they mean?

Comment: Seeing Alexandr's score, the point (-1) was counted in his score. They may be denoting a bye point with (-1). For Kollars and Elham, the point(-0) did not affect their respective scores. It's possible they decided not to play the last 2 and 1 rounds, respectively.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish That sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to read cross tables with odd symbols such as these can be frustrating. Searching online has not produced much explicitly explaining the symbols you've asked about. However, my search did eventually find a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSfcNq0t_NE) explaining how to read results such as you are seeing, which are generated by the Swiss Manager software. Rather that reading "- 1" as "minus one" and "- 0" as "minus zero", the "-" indicates that the player was unpaired that round. The "0" or "1" (or "1/2") indicate the number of points the player received that round. (Note that for other players the column where the "-" appears has a "w" or "s" for white or black respectively. It seems the software is German, thus they use weiß and schwarz.)

Thus, we see that the dashes ("-" characters) indicate that the player in question was not paired against opponents in the rounds in question. This is somewhat backed up by [Fier's Chess Results page for the tournament](https://chess-results.com/tnr793016.aspx?lan=1&art=9&fed=BRA&flag=30&snr=98) which explicitly states that he received a bye in the next to last round. I've been unable to find a source explicitly confirming that Kollars withdrew with two rounds remaining and Elham withdrew before the final round. However, it makes sense that this is what happened based on the - 0 scores involved. A withdrawal by Kollars with two rounds to go would have left an odd number of players in the tournament, necessitating a bye for someone, and we have seen that it went to Fier. If Elham withdrew prior to the last round, there would then be an even number of players remaining, so everyone still in the tournament was paired.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing Alexandr's score, the point (-1) was counted in his score. They may be denoting a bye point with (-1). For Kollars and Elham, the point(-0) did not affect their respective scores. It's possible they decided not to play the last 2 and 1 rounds, respectively, due to some reason.